# Access a function pointer without parenthesis

Tags: c, pointers, function, macros, parentheses

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getAns(void);
int num;

int main() 
{
    int (*current_ans)(void);
    current_ans = &getAns;
    // HERE
    printf("%d", current_ans());    

}

int getAns()
{
    return num + 3;
}
```

However, is it possible to have something in the `// HERE` spot that allows the next line to be `printf("%d", current_ans);` which accesses getAns() in a roundabout way?

Comment: Not exactly what you wanted, but in case you don't know - you can do `int v = current_ans();` and then pass `v` to printf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you can not , because the `()` is necessary to tell the compiler it is an function call.
However, if you **really** want to do it，you can do :

```
#define current_ans current_ans()
```

Answer (score 6):

Though I agree with pierr's answer, the

```
#define current_ans current_ans()
```

will make the code very much **unreadable**

Comment: +1. And actually putting that macro will make the `main` code garbage.

Answer (score 1):

What about "#define current_ans myRoundaboutFnName()"

Answer (score 1):

No because `current_ans` and `current_ans()` are different things. Without the parenthesis, both `current_ans` and `getAns` are a function pointers, while with parenthesis, they are function calls. If you think of the parenthesis as sort of dereferencing the pointer by executing the code, essentially what you are asking is to treat the pointer and the contents of the pointer as one in the same.